# Jetpack Compose, recompositing doesn't work when the compose layout is not in the foreground [Blur]

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

Recomposition breaks if a view is added to the layout container from above.
Situation: there is a profile screen, by tapping on the cell with the number, we load information in the back, whether the user can change the phone and, accordingly, turn the progress bar. If it cannot, we show an error (a custom view that is simply added to the very top of the container), after that the composition screen freezes and does not render changes, CircularProgressIndicator instead of hiding - just hangs. But it is worth clicking in any other place, the screen starts to be drawn correctly. In the photo below, the progress bar is stuck:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
if (rightIconId != null && !isLoading) {
    RightIcon()
} else if (isLoading) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

Calling validate() on the container does not fix the bug.

Update.
It turned out that the blur was breaking the rendering of the UI.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266807258

Comment: Without the understandable code is impossible to help you.

Comment: Please provide code for described ux of the screen, `@Composable fun` of the profile screen